# User menu tab content

Tags: hooks, routes

On the /user page i've created two tabs:

```
function hook_menu() {

    $items['user/%/My-Courses'] = array(
        'title' => 'My Courses',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('hook_form'),
        'access callback' => 'hook_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

    $items['user/%/Privacy-Statement'] = array(
        'title' => 'Privacy Statement',
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('hook_form'),
        'access callback' => 'hook_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    );

    return $items;
}
```

What i'm trying to do is add a link to the my courses tab, and a privacy statement (just text) to the privacy statement tab.

```
function hook_form(){

$form['privacy'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#value' => 'Privacy statement',
  );

 // returns whatever you want to appear in that tab. 
 $form['link1'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => t('This will show the customers courses.'),
 );

 return $form;
}
```

The problem is that it's adding both the link and statement to both tabs.

How would I go about targeting each tab individually?

Comment: Are you sure the `'page arguments' => array('hook_form')` line is the one you are actually using?

Comment: No, I was trying to contain a bit of anonymity for the company and code i'm working on/for :) good catch though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be better off creating *2 separate forms for each tab*, but if you want one form to handle both you can use the function [`menu_get_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_item/7) to determine the menu path that routed to the form.

```
  $menu_item = menu_get_item();
  if(isset($menu_item['path']) && $menu_item['path'] == 'user/%/Privacy-Statement') {
    //@TODO: Add form elements specific to privacy tab
  }
```

Comment: Creating two separate forms for each tab sounds like the direction I should be going in. How would I go about doing that, if you you mind me asking? Is it done within the same hook_form?

Comment: For each menu item in `hook_menu()` just use a different `page arguments` item in your array (e.g. `array('nspf_courses_form')` & `array('nspf_privacy_form')`). Then make sure to create a copy of your `nspf_form` form building function that has the same name (e.g. `function nspf_courses_form()` & `function nspf_privacy_form()`)